# stat() failed : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, stat

I want to get list of files and folders with permissions etc. but for every item I'm getting stat error "No such file or directory" and list contains only items "." and ".."

Code:

```
list<string> res;
DIR *dirp;
dirp = opendir("/");
struct dirent *dp;
while ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL){
    stringstream ss;
    struct stat fileStat;
    if(stat(dp->d_name, &fileStat) < 0)    {
        std::cout << "stat() failed: " << std::strerror(errno) << "(" << dp->d_name << ")" << endl;
        continue;
    }


    ss << ( (S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-" )
     << ( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-")
     << ((fileStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-") << "\t"
     << fileStat.st_nlink << "\t"
     << fileStat.st_uid << "\t"
     << fileStat.st_gid << "\t"
     << fileStat.st_size << "\t";

    char mbstr[100];
    time_t t = (time_t)fileStat.st_mtim.tv_sec;        
    struct tm *tminfo = localtime ( &t );
    strftime(mbstr, sizeof(mbstr), "%b %d %H:%M", tminfo  );
    ss << mbstr << "\t"
       << dp->d_name;
    res.push_back(ss.str());
}

for( string s : res ){
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
...
stat() failed: No such file or directory(usr)
stat() failed: No such file or directory(var)
stat() failed: No such file or directory(home)
stat() failed: No such file or directory(etc)
stat() failed: No such file or directory(bin)
drwxrwxr-x      9       1000    1000    4096    May 29 02:08    .
drwxrwxr-x      3       1000    1000    4096    Mar 16 22:36    ..
```

The example above is for root "/" and I have tried lots of directories but the error does not occur only for current directory ".".

Can you tell me please how to avoid this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing [stat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) on a directory name, **not on a path**.
i.e. you are executing it on "usr" instead of "/usr"

To avoid your problem, make sure to call stat on a path (that your while loop will probably build)

Comment: Right, you have to append `dp->d_name` to the path that you gave to `readdir()` -- and more generally, you may have to insert a `'/'` character between them if there isn't already one there.